# How to get the average time between multiple dates

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is bucket my customers based on their transaction frequency. I have the date recorded for every time they transact but I can't work out to get the average delta between *each* date. What I effectively want is a table showing me:

```
| User | Average Frequency
|  1   | 15
|  2   | 15
|  3   | 35
...
```

The data I currently have is formatted like this:

```
| User | Transaction Date
|  1   | 2018-01-01
|  1   | 2018-01-15
|  1   | 2018-02-01
|  2   | 2018-06-01
|  2   | 2018-06-18
|  2   | 2018-07-01
|  3   | 2019-01-01
|  3   | 2019-02-05
...
```

So basically, each customer will have multiple transactions and I want to understand how to get the delta between **each** date and then average of the deltas.

I know the `datediff` function and how it works but I can't work out how to split them transactions up. I also know that the `offset` function is available in tools like Looker but I don't know the syntax behind it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ you can use [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to get a delayed `Transaction Date` and then use [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to get the difference between two consecutive dates. You can then take the average of those values:

```
SELECT User, AVG(delta) AS `Average Frequency`
FROM (SELECT User, 
             DATEDIFF(`Transaction Date`, LAG(`Transaction Date`) OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY `Transaction Date`)) AS delta
      FROM transactions) t
GROUP BY User
```

Output:

```
User    Average Frequency
1       15.5
2       15
3       35
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5K2MZk9mMnXXaSyqAyhCmx/1)

Comment: I'm not using mysql 8 I'm afraid so do not have access to `LAG`. Shame as it seems to work really well in demo

Comment: @LiamCox yeah as you can see by comparing my answer with Strawberry's it really makes life simpler. Oh well, something to look forward to when you upgrade.

Comment: any chance you can help me still? Strawberry's solution isn't working for me and seems uninterested in trying to help me fix it.

Comment: Just looking at the error in the comment you posted to Strawberry you've got `as my_table x` which is  invalid as you've made two aliases for one table, I think you just want `as x`

Comment: but Strawberry's code has `FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y` - I don't understand what `my_table y` is

Comment: @LiamCox `my_table` is supposed to refer to your "table" so everything in the parentheses i.e. `(select user_id, DATE_FORMAT(payment_success_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as payment_date from payment_data where DATE_FORMAT(payment_success_date,'%Y-%m') >= '2018-04' group by 1,2)` should go into his query everywhere you see `my_table`

Comment: it's a solution to the problem though that legitimately works. I've managed to make Strawberry's solution work with your feedback so it's been solved.

Comment: @LiamCox fair enough. I'm glad you managed to get Strawberry's solution to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to say other than use a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT User, AVG(DATEDIFF(...))
FROM ...
GROUP BY User
```

Comment: @Strawberry you got me on that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(user INT NOT NULL
,transaction_date DATE
,PRIMARY KEY(user,transaction_date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2018-01-01'),
(1,'2018-01-15'),
(1,'2018-02-01'),
(2,'2018-06-01'),
(2,'2018-06-18'),
(2,'2018-07-01'),
(3,'2019-01-01'),
(3,'2019-02-05');

SELECT user
     , AVG(delta) avg_delta
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , DATEDIFF(x.transaction_date,MAX(y.transaction_date)) delta 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.user = x.user 
          AND y.transaction_date < x.transaction_date 
        GROUP 
           BY x.user
            , x.transaction_date
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY user;
+------+-----------+
| user | avg_delta |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |   15.5000 |
|    2 |   15.0000 |
|    3 |   35.0000 |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x join my_table y on y.user_id = x.user_id and y.payment_date < x.payment_dat' at line 13"

Comment: my proper code looks like this«`select
    x.*,
    DATEDIFF(x.payment_date,MAX(y.payment_date)) delta
from
    (select
        user_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(payment_success_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as payment_date
    from
        payment_data
    where
        DATE_FORMAT(payment_success_date,'%Y-%m') >= '2018-04'
    group by 1,2) as my_table x 
join my_table y 
on y.user_id = x.user_id 
and y.payment_date < x.payment_date
group by x.user_id, x.payment_date`

Comment: I'm trying to build the (a) table before I average it to understand how this actually works...

Comment: The (a) table is simply everything in parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, i get that. But I'm getting the error above when I try to run the code I've copied in which is just the (a) table.